# Bitcoin transaction failed to broadcast (code 66)

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, mempool

I am using bitcoind. I got this error while trying to send a transaction:

CommitTransaction(): Transaction cannot be broadcast immediately, mempool min fee not met, 6835 < 7865 (code 66)

The balance was removed from my wallet and yet the node does not seem to retry sending this txid again. How do i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be rebroadcast by your wallet automatically. However, you may want to bump the fee (`bumpfee` RPC command) if it's urgent as you are paying so low fees that you got evicted from your mempool.

Comment: Thanks, it was eventually rebroadcasted like you said